# Odoo Automation On Update Run More than Once, How To Restrict?

Tags: automation, odoo, ticket-system

I'm currently using Odoo 12.0+e-20181025 and I'm currently using the Automated Action feature of it to send email whenever the ticket has been updated by someone. I put two different actions, one is to send an email while the other is to make an internal log in the internal log (logger) of the ticket.
The on update domain is as the following:

`["&",["user_id","!=",False],["team_id","!=",False]]`

At first, it works. But then I noticed that some of them tend to be activated more than once, six (6) times to be exact. As I tried to look for the culprit, I found that it was whenever I choose the "**Assigned to**" field and/or "**Helpdesk Team**" field. For some reason I don't know, every time I changed them, the system perceived it as more than one update. It will work normal on any other field.

Can anyone help me how to either (1) make my domain in the automated action work only once each time or (2) how to make the system read my action of filling the field as only one update.Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I suggest to restrict multiple attempts from scheduled action.

- Add a flag (boolean) field on your target object,
- When a scheduled action is executed, search only flag = False,
- Afterwards, when you done with event email send, update current record set with flag = True
- Now, flag = True will never fetch by scheduled action --- see 2nd point.

Comment: Okay, I tried it but for some reason all of the boolean turned to true after each execution. Is this normal? I mean, I didn't even put a field to interact with them on the form.

Comment: No. You are iterate multiple sales orders. correct ? Update flag at the end of each iteration.

Comment: Not multiple sales order. Only one. In one helpdesk ticket it will do one automation task. Or at least I hope it will do one automation task. Instead, it did five automation tasks, as if the record has been updated five times.

Comment: Got it. Then you can check condition `if flag = True` then do not set any value (true)